# table content breaks into next page

Tags: php, css, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wktmltopdf version 0.12.3

My pdf table rows are broke into the next page in the end of the page: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XciXS.png)

Comment: where's you making the layout of table? inside php/html and after that printing it ?

Comment: read about [page-break-inside](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp) CSS property.

Comment: It's better if  you upload image here